# sbt console doesn't allow input

Tags: scala, sbt

I've been trying to use `sbt` for one of my projects, however I've ran into the following problem - when I try to use `sbt console` to get the `scala`'s REPL, it just doesn't allow any input. Example session:

```
[lared@lt foo]$ sbt

[info] Set current project to foo (in build file:/tmp/foo/)

> console

[info] Updating {file:/tmp/foo/}foo...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.3 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

I can not type anything. It doesn't seem to take much RAM/CPU time. The problem is reproducible in any directory, regardless of if it does have a proper project structure (for example [the SBT Hello World tutorial](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Hello.html)) or not.

I'm using `sbt 0.13.1` and the JDK/Scala versions as seen above on Fedora 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by deleting `~/.ivy2/` and (perhaps unrelated) migration to Oracle Java 1.7 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to get the Fedora 24 installed sbt 0.13.1 console to work either so I [downloaded the latest sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html) (currently 0.13.12), unzipped into `/opt` and add the `sbt` binary to my path before `/usr/bin/sbt`.

The earlier suggestion to delete ~/.ivy2 did not work for me.